# Embedding PDF in Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pdf, embed

Goal is to run this subroutine in an Access application, which embeds a PDF document in a new Excel workbook.  The sub works properly with a text file, but will give error "Run-time error '1004': Document not saved." with a PDF file.  The code breaks on the SaveAs method.  Why does one file-type embed, and the PDF file-type not work?  Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub SavePDFInWorkBook()
    Dim xlObj As New Excel.Application  ' Excel application
    Dim wbkObj As Excel.workbook        ' workbook object
    Dim wstObj As Excel.Worksheet       ' worksheet object
    Dim oleObj As Excel.OLEObject       ' embeded object
    Dim EmbedFile, MyWbk As String

    MyWbk = "M:\SS\DD\Projects\cash_dep2000\TEST.xlsx"
    EmbedFile = "M:\SS\DD\Projects\cash_dep2000\DaytonFreight.pdf"

    Set wbkObj = xlObj.Workbooks.Add    ' workbook is added in open condition in memory
    Set wstObj = wbkObj.Worksheets(1)   ' workbook is created with one worksheet
    Set oleObj = wstObj.OLEObjects.Add(, EmbedFile, False, True)

    wbkObj.SaveAs (MyWbk)               ' saves workbook to folder
    wbkObj.Close                        ' closes workbook in folder
    Set oleObj = Nothing
    Set wstObj = Nothing
    Set wbkObj = Nothing
    Set xlObj = Nothing

    MsgBox ("Test Complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: Tested code. Also not getting the file to save when embedding pdf. Images are not actually added to the sheet, just a box with image name, except for pdf type, just a big empty box and no file name. These are links to the actual files. Is this what you want? The pdf link works, just won't save file.

Answer (score 0):

This works to embed pdf icon/link but it also opens the pdf. Aggravating.
`ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:="C:\Users\June\MyStuff\DMV.pdf", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
        "C:\WINDOWS\Installer\{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AB0000000001}\PDFFile_8.ico", _
        IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:="whatever you want").Activate`

I can manually save the file but SaveAs code for macro-enabled workbook errors. More aggravating. Maybe modifying to your object manipulation code will work.